# Using vim-quickrun for "PHP REPL style"

Tags: php, vim

I'm trying to get some "repl-like" feature for PHP, inside vim.
Basically, what I want is to be able to visually select a part of my script, execute it, and see the result in a separate buffer. 
But I don't want to execute the whole current file (so :!php % doesn't do the trick ...)

I found the vim-quickrun plugin, which seems to greatly fit that need, but can't make it work and when looking for more documentation, most of the result I get are in japanese (I don't speak japanese :( ... )

For now, I have installed the plugin via Vundle, but have not added any extra configuration to my .vimrc

From inside a file, I can type

```
...
echo 'hello quickrun sh test'
...
```

=> visual select the date line, and type

```
:QuickRun sh
```

I got my hello world printed, all fine

But if I do

```
...
echo 'hellow quickrun php'
...
```

=> visual select ...

```
:QuickRun php
```

I just get a buffer with just the same text that I typed, no execution ...

Does someone already achieved something like this ?
Thanks a lot !

EDIT :
 PHP is correctly added to my PATH. Added the 2 config lines suggested below ... Sadly, it doesn't change anything :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the php flags around your php code, like any php script (it always starts in plain text mode):

```
...
<?php
echo 'hellow quickrun php';
?>
....
```

Then you can select only one part with `QuickRun`, but don't forget to select the flags as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use that plugin, but I think you need to configure something like this in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:quickrun_config = {}
let g:quickrun_config.php = {'command' : 'php'}
```

and have the `php` executable in your PATH.

Answer (score -1):

The following solution does not use vim-quickrun but allows you to visually select, execute and see the result just as you like. You need [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) with [phpsh](http://www.phpsh.org/) :

1. First, install the vim-slime plugin. It allows to send lines and visually selected chunks of code from VIM to a screen or tmux session.
2. Now install screen: On Ubuntu, do `sudo apt-get install screen`.
3. Open a terminal and start screen with a session name: `screen -S sessionname`.
4. Open a second terminal and start vim. Write some code, visually select it and press `<C-c><C-c>`, that is two times CTRL+C. You will be asked for the session name, use `sessionname` as before. The selected lines will be sent to the first terminal just as if you had written them directly there.
5. To make use of this functionality, you need to start an interactive PHP shell in the first terminal, such as phpsh.